# It's possible to save report parameter wrote by user?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, rdl

I have report where I ask user to write path to dir of files. This parameter have default value on start, but I want to allow user change it. From moment where he change it parameter wrote by user will be displayed as default on next render time.

Edit:
I use Buissnes Inteligence and SQL SERVER 2008r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done in SSRS alone.

What you could do would be to write a procedure to produce your report output, which accepts the directory path as a parameter and saves it to a user lookup table, before producing the report data.

You could then use a query on the user table to produce the default value for the parameter in SSRS.

Comment: I don't need this already. But Your idea is possible the only way to realize what I wrote.